How to solve npm install(npm err 1)?
Who can help me for npm package install error?
Steps: I've tried:
Uninstalled and reinstalled Node.js, but the issue persists.
Deleted the node_modules folder and re-ran npm install, but encountered the same error.
Cleared the npm cache using npm cache clean --force.
Node version: v20
npm version: v10
OS: Windows
npm error path C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract
npm error command failed
npm error command C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe /d /s /c node-gyp rebuild
npm error Bu ��z�mde projeler tek tek derlenir. Paralel bir derlemeyi etkinle�tirmek i�in l�tfen "-m" anahtar�n� ekleyin.
npm error   tesseract_bindings.cc
npm error C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract\src\tesseract_bindings.cc(7,1): warning C4005: 'BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION': makro yeniden tan�mlama [C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract\build\tesseract_bindings.vcxproj]
npm error C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract\src\tesseract_bindings.cc : message : �nceki 'BUILDING_NODE_EXTENSION' tan�m�na bak�n [C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract\build\tesseract_bindings.vcxproj]
npm error C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract\src\tesseract_baseapi.h(10,10): fatal error C1083: i�erme dosyas� a��lam�yor: 'baseapi.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract\build\tesseract_bindings.vcxproj]
npm error gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm error gyp info using node-gyp@10.1.0
npm error gyp info using node@20.18.0 | win32 | x64
npm error gyp info find Python using Python version 3.12.6 found at "C:\Python312\python.exe"
npm error gyp info find VS using VS2019 (16.11.35325.158) found at:
npm error gyp info find VS "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools"
npm error gyp info find VS run with --verbose for detailed information
npm error gyp info spawn C:\Python312\python.exe
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\gyp\\gyp_main.py',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'binding.gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-f',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'msvs',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\hack\\node_modules\\tesseract\\build\\config.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\addon.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-I',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.18.0\\include\\node\\common.gypi',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dvisibility=default',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_root_dir=C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\node-gyp\\Cache\\20.18.0',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_gyp_dir=C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_lib_file=C:\\\\Users\\\\lenovo\\\\AppData\\\\Local\\\\node-gyp\\\\Cache\\\\20.18.0\\\\<(target_arch)\\\\node.lib',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dmodule_root_dir=C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\hack\\node_modules\\tesseract',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--depth=.',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--no-parallel',
npm error gyp info spawn args '--generator-output',
npm error gyp info spawn args 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\Desktop\\hack\\node_modules\\tesseract\\build',
npm error gyp info spawn args '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp info spawn C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe
npm error gyp info spawn args [
npm error gyp info spawn args 'build\\binding.sln',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/clp:Verbosity=minimal',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/nologo',
npm error gyp info spawn args '/p:Configuration=Release;Platform=x64'
npm error gyp info spawn args ]
npm error gyp ERR! build error
npm error gyp ERR! stack Error: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\BuildTools\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe` failed with exit code: 1
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:209:23)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:519:28)
npm error gyp ERR! stack at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:294:12)
npm error gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.22631
npm error gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm error gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\lenovo\Desktop\hack\node_modules\tesseract
npm error gyp ERR! node -v v20.18.0
npm error gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v10.1.0
npm error gyp ERR! not ok
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-10-25T17_46_03_555Z-debug-0.log```


it didn't work
npm error code: 'ERR_INVALID_OBJECT_DEFINE_PROPERTY'  npm error Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
